# Struggling to attatch to application moduler in Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to automate a process to do with the Command Prompt. I have managed to successfully open cmd using using the Utility Environment Action. However once it is opened, I cannot successfully attach so that I can spy, and type elements into the cmd.

If I try to use the Navigate and then "attach" I am faced with the following error: 'External AppMan reader thread exited before response from query'
If anybody can provide any information on this topic this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: The "External AppMan reader thread exited before response from query" error is often get when you have several instances open at the same time. Make sure in the "Windows Task Manager" that you don't have any "cmd.exe". Also, what do you want to spy in the Command prompt ? There is nothing to spy

Comment: Hi there. Thank you very much for your reply. So I have looked to see if there are any instances elsewhere open however there are not, and the AppMan issue continues. And I was just trying to spy the whole cmd so that I can type several commands into it. Would you recommend something different?

Comment: Hi, you can use the "Start Process" objet and launch the cmd.exe with arguments like this `C:\Windowd\System32\cmd.exe /c my-cmd-command`

The /c arguments launch the cmd, execute your commande and then close cmd.exe.

If you want I'll show you an example later, currently I'm with my phone and not home.

Comment: Hi again, if you would be so kind to show an example that would be much appreciated, as I am still having problems with attaching, running the process and then in the middle of the process it un attatches. Regards

Answer (score 1):

So there is how you can launch the "cmd.exe" and execute your command within.

`/c` -> Run your command and then terminate the cmd.exe

`/k` -> Run your command and then return to the cmd.exe window

[image: Start Process]